# ransack specify timezone in search query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, timezone, ransack

I'm trying to find a way where i can tell ransack to use a specific timezone in queries that involve dates or date range. For example ransack by default uses UTC for datetime searches and i want to perform the query using PST timezone, how do i do that? is there any hack or configuration ? Following is an example query that gets generated.

SELECT DISTINCT "orders".* FROM "orders" LEFT OUTER JOIN "customers" ON "customers"."id" = "orders"."customer_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "payments" ON "payments"."order_id" = "orders"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "order_lines" ON "order_lines"."order_id" = "orders"."id" WHERE "orders"."test_transaction" = 'f' AND (("orders"."created_at" >= '2012-11-03 07:00:00.000000' AND "orders"."created_at" <= '2012-11-05 06:59:59.000000'))

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the specifics of Ransack, but typically if you are storing UTC dates in the database, then you should query by UTC values.

If your query dates are in Pacific time, then convert them to UTC before passing them into your query.  You can use a Ruby gem such as [timezone](https://rubygems.org/gems/timezone),  [TZInfo](http://tzinfo.rubyforge.org/), or [ActiveSupport::TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It´s a little dirty but works

```
current_zone = Time.zone.name # Get default time zone
Time.zone = "UTC" #Change to whatever time zone you want. 
@search = Model.search(params[:q]) 
@objects = @search.result
Time.zone = current_zone #Set default time zone
```

Check for timezones in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-local_to_utc